# Duplicate class error with Groovlets

Tags: groovy, groovlet

I am trying to work with a Catch-all groovy script for my groovlets. This is what I did

```
public class GroovletServletCatchAll extends GroovyServlet { 
    public URLConnection getResourceConnection(String name) throws ResourceException { 
        return super.getResourceConnection("CatchAll.groovy"); 
    } 
}
```

Now, with any code in `CatchAll.groovy` file, I get the error

```
jndi:/localhost/web_app/CatchAll.groovy: 1: 
Invalid duplicate class definition of class CatchAll. 
One of the classes is an explicit generated class using the class statement, 
the other is a class generated from the script body based on the file name.
```

Why is the first class getting generated? I do not have any other class in my code. Only the Catch-all script and the extended servlet.

---

This was the stripped code for which I got the above mentioned error

```
  println """
  Hello, ${request.remoteHost}: ${new Date()}
  """
```

Oddly enough, if I remove the `new Date()` clause above, the first error goes away, and I get an stackOverflow in the CatchAll constructor (keeps on calling itself).

This was what I saw repeating(among other trace) in the logs

```
    at groovy.lang.GroovyObjectSupport.<init>(GroovyObjectSupport.java:32)
    at groovy.lang.Script.<init>(Script.java:40)
    at groovy.lang.Script.<init>(Script.java:37)
    at CatchAll.<init>(CatchAll.groovy)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
```

I have posted the same question [here](http://groovy.329449.n5.nabble.com/duplicate-class-error-with-Groovlets-tt5716652.html) as well

Comment: What does `CatchAll.groovy` look like?

Comment: I tried with the simplest of scripts (one liners) and it kept on failing

Comment: Can you post the code for the script you tried?

Comment: @tim_yates : Please see the updates in the main content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not go deep enough to resolve the strange behavior, but there was an easier solution. I added this to direct all the requests to a single script.

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>resource.name.replacement</param-name>
    <param-value>CatchAll.groovy</param-value>
</init-param>

<init-param>
    <param-name>resource.name.regex</param-name>
    <param-value>/.*</param-value>
</init-param>
```

Answer (score 0):

have to correct my previous answer: the fix was not the code change I posted previously, but rather the downgrade from 2.4.3 to 2.3.9. In 2.4.3 the GroovyServlet itself works fine, but extending its setVariables, getScriptUri, getResourceConnection and getScriptUriAsFile did lead to the named problem.

still investigating further.